# nested eager-loading using load()

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

A Post can have many Comments.

A Comment can have many Likes.

When I show a post, I eager-load its comments. For each of these comments, I want to display the fact that the post's author did like the comment or not.

So I found myself in a situation where I do need to `load()` instead of chaining one more `with()`, all because I need to retrieve the post's author id first (`$post->author->id`). The post's author id then goes down the nest through the closures.

Despite the fact that this actually works great (it does indeed eager load), I'm super annoyed at how ugly my controller now looks.

Is there a way to `scope` a `load()`, just like the way one would query `scope` a `with()`?
I would like to move that chunk inside a trait in an elegant way and not let it reside in my controller.
Right I'm just planning to move that disgusting bit inside a function, but I really wish I could just keep piping/chaining `$post = Post::query()->...->findOrFail($id)->???...`

Screenshots attached below. I'm asking for guidance. The code works.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved it inside a method in a trait.

[image]

[image]